# Process.WaitForExit() is not waiting

Tags: c#, process, waitforexit

I wrote a small method that starts a process and then should wait until the process has exited. But it's not waiting until the process has finished. "test" will be printed immediately.

This is the code:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(p_Path)
{
    UseShellExecute = true
};
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();  //<- its not working
MessageBox.Show("test");
```

The process is an Excel document.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If it doesn't wait it means the process you start either start another process himself and close like a game launcher window for example or that you start a process that catch other startup and grab the context and open on his own like a browser for example

Comment: Maybe the process that you are starting is just a launcher, that launches another process?

Comment: The process is an excel document. Do you have an other solution to track, when the excel will be closed?